# Make a prime number from specified number, by concatenating some more digits on its right?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

I am given a number, I don't know whether it's prime or not. The algo says, 
For eg - 
Step 1 - Convert char to ints. (Hello - 72101108108111) Ascii values
Step 2 - Make a large number.

1. Convert char to ints. (Hello - 72101108108111) Ascii values
2. Make a larger number (72101108108111).
3. Make this number a prime by adding more digits.
   .
   .
   .
   .
   I want to know, how the algo expects to add some more digits to the right , So I would get a prime?

Comment: Algo?  What is that?

Comment: @Umberto "algo"=algorithm

Comment: What does step 2 means ? It only means concatenating the ascii values ?

Comment: Yes,thats what it means @Traklon

Comment: That's a pretty strange algorithm, what's the point?

Comment: It was used by Alan Turing, and was taught in MIT, as a basic cryptography algorithm. Though it has flaws, it was a good basis for modern cryptography. @Henrik

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is the following :

1. Add a digit at the end of the number to make it of the form $6k+1$ (this is always doable).
2. Test the number for primality using the Miller-Rabin Test.
3. If the number is prime, stop and return the number.
4. The number isn't prime. Add a $3$ at the end. The number still has the form $6k+1$. Go to step 2.

Making the number of the form $6k+1$ prevents the number you create to be divisible by $2$ and $3$ and increases the probability that you find a prime number.

EDIT : Unfortunately this doesn't work for all numbers. I would advise you to test all odd numbers (not multiples of 5) that can be produced by concatenating numbers at the right, in the increasing order, and testing each one of them with a primailty test, as in Charles' answer.

Comment: I suspect that it does not -- that specially-chosen numbers will produce only composites. This phenomenon should mirror that of Sierpiński and Riesel numbers.

Comment: The algorithm constructs a sequence $a+3\,n$ with $a$ and $3$ coprime. By Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions, there are infinite primes in it.

Comment: Yes, that was more or less what I thought, but I never know if there are some hypothesis I forget. Anyway I proposed this to get a speed boost by getting more likely to have a prime number but since the number grows faster, I don't know if it is worth it compared to the simpler brute force proposed by @Charles.

Comment: @JuliánAguirre: Dirichlet's theorem doesn't let you find infinitely many primes of the form k, k3, k33, k333, ... [where juxtaposition represents decimal concatenation], which is what we're doing here.

Comment: OK, here's an explicit example: 131116183. It's already 1 mod 6, but you can keep it there by adding another 3 if you like. But no matter how many 3s you add you'll never get a prime number.

Comment: @Charles Right, I misunderstood "add a 3 at the end".

Comment: Alright I think this discussion is interesting so I don't want to delete the answer - that I'm going to edit -. However, If I could get a downvote so @Charles 's answer gets above mine, that would be awesome. Thanks for the counterexample !

Comment: @Traklon: Thanks for the edit. I don't want you to delete either -- especially since the counterexample took more effort to find than my actual answer!

Answer (score 3):

Use brute force. Take the large number $N$ and test if any of $10N+1,10N+3,10N+7,$ or $10N+9$ are prime. If so you're done. If not, test $100N+1,100N+3,\ldots,100N+97,100N+99.$ If none of those are prime check $1000N+1$ and so on. This is guaranteed (by the Prime Number Theorem) to eventually find a prime.